# Using Mendeley or similar reference help with LaTeX editor Atom

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, bibtool

Is it possible to use Mendeley within the Atom environment writing LaTeX text? Or is there a similar tool?

I really dislike Microsoft Word, but I think the reference / bibliography help with Mendeley is fantastic!

Comment: Sure, you can use Mendeley with ***any***  decent text editor. Export your Mendeley references to BibTeX(*bib) format and then use it with LaTeX. Some  could have some tools to help you to search references and insert the proper LaTeX citation  command like  `\cite{Kagan1967}`, but you can obtain that command form Mendely  (Ctrl+K)., so this is f little importance.

Answer (score 1):

Mendeley can export a `.bib` file which can be called with `\addbibresource{yourfile.bib}` in the preamble of your document (so, like any other `.bib`). Mendeley has a blog post which explains how to set this up. [Here is a link.](https://blog.mendeley.com/2012/03/24/how-to-series-generate-bibtex-files-for-your-collections-for-use-in-latex-part-3-of-12/)

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "within the Atom environment", so I don't know if this answers your question in that regard. This solution will allow you to use the normal citation commands in Atom which will render correctly when typeset in the customary way (i.e. `pdflatex` & `biber`).

I know that there are packages for Atom which allow you to compile a document straight from Atom, and at these are usually compatible with `.bib` bibliographies. [Here is link to one such package, although I've never used this one myself.](https://atom.io/packages/atom-latex) I think that is the closest you can get to having this functionality "within the Atom environment".